# Manipulate with existing SVG file? (SVG file to raphael object)

Tags: javascript, webview, svg, raphael, titanium-mobile

When I found about [raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) SVG library I thought it would be peace of cake to do my SVG stuff. But I see that raphael can't import SVG file and from reading other stacks I didn't found any good solution. I saw a few online converters SVG-to-Raphael but I am looking for something that I could programmatically use.

Cross browser compatibility is not a must since I am using this in a mobile development with Titanium Studio.

How can achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import ?

Comment: I did run onto that one also but I saw somebody else on StackOverflow tried it and didn't get good results. These are the one's I've found but it looks that none of them is complete: [SVG into Raphael](http://bkp.ee/atirip/convert-svg-into-raphael), [raphael svg import classic](https://github.com/crccheck/raphael-svg-import-classic), [raphael SVG import](https://github.com/wout/raphael-svg-import) and the "manual ones": [ready steady raphael](http://readysetraphael.com/), [SVG2RaphaelJS](http://toki-woki.net/p/SVG2RaphaelJS/).

Comment: Do you need to convert a lot of assets or just a couple? It's relatively trivial just going through the source svg and putting it into Raphael attributes, depending on the complexity of the vector illustrations.

Comment: I give up from raphael and I started using SVG with canvas form transformations. I don't think I could convert SVG to raphael objects without any mistakes.